# Родительская и дочерняя тема - проблема со страницами

Tags: wordpress

Есть тема Spoti-EY-Custom и есть ее дочерняя тема. Именно она и включена.
Каким-то образом старые страницы (page) используют родительский шаблон, а все новые дочернюю. Перекопал весь шаблон, не могу понять, как такое вообще может быть.
Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Страничный кеш?

Comment: Нет, оказалось автор спрятал плагин для роутинга темы )